# React Router and browser history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history

I'm thoroughly lost and would like to ask for a recomendation on how to implement browser history inside my app.

With Router, all i have is a single component which gets assigned pages based on which page i'm on. pages and text inside app is acquired from an api, and whenever i click a button, the api gets called again.

```
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route to="/" component={Body} />
...
```

which probably doesnt even work as it should, because the Link tags are on the buttons, and they point to /page/number:

```
const renderPageNumbers = apiPagingSliced.map((links, index)  => {
        return <Link key={index} to={`/page/${links.label}`}>
                <button key={index} id={links.label} 
                onClick={props.handleClick} 
                className={(links.active ? "mark-page" : "") + " " + (links.url === null ? "remove-btn" : "")}
                >{links.label}
                </button></Link>
    }
    )
```

i've managed to get it working so that i get "www.webpage.com/page/3" for example. But when i press back in browser, it only changes the url into previous page, doesn't do anything else. How do i implement a functional back/forward history function?

Answer (score 0):

First you should add a route to the `/page/(some number)`

And this is done like this:

```
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route to="/" component={Body} />
<Route to="/page/:id" component={Page} />
...
```

And now in the Page component import a react router dom hook called useParams

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const Page = () => {

  const history = useHistory()

  //pageID will be equal to the page number

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={event => history.goBack`}>Go back!</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, but if i'm not mistaken, this is a new button that goes back one page, right? I'm asking about browser's back and forward buttons on the top left

Comment: @hackinghippie Oh sorry. Try using another react-router-dom hook called useHistory.
I edited my previous answer, take a look.

Comment: i really appreciate you helping me :) but i tried working around it and it still doesn't work. the thing is, i don't have a seperate Page component. It's all in class Body.js. Body is connected to Paging component, where buttons get created, assigned numbers and id's, and then returned to Body. So i need to reach that Paging function.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add the route params example : "/:id"

```
<Route to="/some_page/:id" component={SomePage} />
```

Then import useHistory and UseParams from react-router :

```
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

let { id } = useParams();

let history = useHistory();


<button  onClick={() => history.push(`/some_page/${id}`)}> Go to page </button>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. how would this work if i don't have a seperate "page" component?
i have the main class component - Body, which is connected to a funct component that evaluates pages and page buttons and has the button id's. So i'm calling {Body} instead of {SomePage}, but the id's are in the function component. no idea how to connect it